# King of the Center

Tags: python

For a 3D volume of shape (N, K, L), what is the most pythonic way to get an index array of the following order:

```py
[N//2, (N//2)-1, (N//2)+1, (N//2)-2, (N//2)+2, ..., (N//2)-(N//2)+1, (N//2)+((N//2)-1), 0]
```

Background:
I have a binary 3D volume with a single complex 3D geometric object at its center (represented through `True` values). I would like to select the centermost slice `n` of the volume for which `np.any(vol[n,:,:])` returns `True`.

I currently solve the issue as follows:

```py
# find the most centric slice that contains True values
idx_t =  np.where(vol==True)[0]
center = min(idx_t, key=lambda x : abs(max((vol.shape[0]-1)//2, 0) - x))
```

However, for larger volumes, using `np.where` seems quite wasteful. In particular, since the criterion is fulfilled by one of the three centermost slices in most cases. My idea is to instead iterate the slices using the array described above and exit the loop once a slice meets the criterion.

Comment: Do K and L never come into it?

Comment: if you problem to do it in single line then don't do it in one line but create normal `for`-loop and if it will work then you may try to convert it to single line.

Comment: @Ry- actually not. Sorry if that was not clear or is confusing. My aim is to select the centermost slice that fulfills a particular criterion. I would, therefore, only iterate over the first dimension.

Comment: @furas fair! I implemented versions based on `for`-loops, but so far, non were quicker than the above approach. As I put some time into it, I was simply curious if an itertool or similar exists to smoothly and efficiently create such an array.

Comment: first create `working` code - and `for`-loop is simpler for this, and later try to make it faster.